# pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (numpy 1.19.5), Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.20.0'),

Tags: numpy, pytorch, python-imageio

I find some version conflict.

pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (numpy 1.19.5 (/home/mehnaz/environments/nnUnet_ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('numpy>=1.20.0'), {'imageio'})

it means I need to install numpy >=1.20.0 instead of numpy 1.19.5(which is currently installed here) and whenever I am trying to install that it gives the following:

ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.20.0

Then I tried using
pip3 install 'numpy==1.20.0'
pip3 install numpy
pip3 install numpy --upgrade
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install numpy
for all cases it gives the same message

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/mehnaz/environments/nnUnet_ve/lib/python3.6/site-packages (1.19.5)

Then i uninstalled numpy and again install numpy for newer version but still it is installing 1.19.5 version and through the following message:

imageio 2.16.0 requires numpy>=1.20.0, but you have numpy 1.19.5 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed numpy-1.19.5

So, in this case, how can I update the numpy version?

Comment: Which python version are you using? Numpy 1.20 not being available sounds like you are using python 3.6.